# Exception building Samples from WSO2 Identity Server examples

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to build the samples which are meant for WSO2 Identiy Server. I am following the steps listed in :

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] 'groupId' is missing. @ line 4, column 109
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountere
d while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] 'groupId' is missing. @ line 4, column 109

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBu
ilder.java:422)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGra
phBuilder.java:419)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor
(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.
java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project [unknown-group-id]:org.wso2.sample.is.sso.agent:1.2.0 (C:\
codes\wso\sso\SSOAgentSample\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'groupId' is missing. @ line 4, column 109
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
gException
```

My pom.xml is same as listed in the link. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the 2nd step given in the example. Then it should work.

Remove the parent entry in the pom.xml file that comes along with the sample. The contents of the pom.xml file will look similar to the following once you remove the parent entry. Alternatively, replace the contents of the pom.xml file with the following code snippet.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <groupId>org.wso2.identity</groupId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>wso2is-identity-samples-sso</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Identity Server : SSO Samples</name>
    <modules>
        <module>SSOAgentSample</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanx. Still i have issues.

Comment: What is it? Whats you Java version?

Comment: jdk1.7.0_75. Error is as follows

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Permission denied: connect -> [Help 1]

Comment: Sorry it was my fault. I was using a  different version 3.3.1 of Apache Maven instead of the one recommended in the wso2 documentation - Apache 3.0.4. Problem is solved